# Compiling an c++ application on Linux and flash it on the TI TIVA TM4C123GH6PM

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, arm, texas-instruments

I'm compiling an application in Linux with a Makefile. My compiler is from Imperas (ovp world). After compiling the application I get a *.elf file which I want to flash on the TI TIVA TM4C123GH6PM with the software Uniflash from TI.
I always get this error, when I try to verify the image: " [ERROR] CORTEX_M4_0: File Loader: Verification failed: Values at address 0x00008000 do not match Please verify target memory and memory map. "

My Makefile looks like this:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IMPERAS_HOME := $(shell getpath.exe "$(IMPERAS_HOME)")
include $(IMPERAS_HOME)/bin/Makefile.include

ifndef IMPERAS_HOME
  IMPERAS_ERROR := $(error "IMPERAS_HOME not defined")
endif

CROSS=ARM_CORTEX_M4F

-include $(IMPERAS_HOME)/lib/$(IMPERAS_ARCH)/CrossCompiler/$(CROSS).makefile.include
ifeq ($($(CROSS)_CXX),)
    IMPERAS_ERROR := $(error "Please install the toolchain to support $(CROSS) ")
endif

OPTIMIZATION=-Os

SRC = $(sort $(wildcard main.cpp))  $(sort $(wildcard Configuration/Configuration.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Segway/Simulation.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Segway/Segway.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Sensor/ADC.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Sensor/ADCSensor.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Antrieb/Motor.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Sensor/GPIOSensor.cpp)) $(sort $(wildcard Timer/Timer.cpp))  $(sort $(wildcard Antrieb/PWM.cpp))

EXE = application.ARM_CORTEX_M4F.elf

all: $(EXE)

%.elf: main.o Segway/Segway.o Timer/Timer.o Sensor/ADC.o Sensor/ADCSensor.o Sensor/GPIOSensor.o  Configuration/Configuration.o Antrieb/Motor.o Antrieb/PWM.o
    $(V)  echo "# Linking $@"
    $(V) $(IMPERAS_LINKXX)  -o $@ $^ $(IMPERAS_LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(V)  echo "# Compiling $<"
    $(V)  $(IMPERAS_CXX) -g -c -o $@ $< $(OPTIMIZATION) -lm

clean:
    -rm -f *.elf *.o

realclean: clean
    -rm -f *.log

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

How can I include the memory map to my Makefile? The memory map is defined in a *.cmd file. Here is a link to the file: https://github.com/LuisAfonso95/TM4C123-Launchpad-Examples/blob/master/srf04/tm4c123gh6pm.cmd

Does anyone has a solution for my problem and can help me?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you!

Johannes

Comment: Please read [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Makefile

```
ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m4
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m4

all : so.bin

clean:
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list

flash.o : flash.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) flash.s -o flash.o

so.o : so.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c so.c -o so.o

so.bin : flash.ld flash.o so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o so.elf -T flash.ld flash.o so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy so.elf so.bin -O binary
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

flash.s

```
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

so.c

```
extern void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );

int notmain ( void )
{
    PUT32(0x20000400,0x12345678);
    return(0);
}
```

make

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m4 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o so.elf -T flash.ld flash.o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.bin -O binary
```

examine disassembly to see that the vector table is in the right place and built right, could toss a global variable in and save a value to it (runtime) to see that that is in the correct place as well if you want.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   00000041    andeq   r0, r0, r1, asr #32
   8:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
   c:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  10:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  14:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  18:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  1c:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  20:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  24:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  28:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  2c:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  30:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  34:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  38:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32
  3c:   00000047    andeq   r0, r0, r7, asr #32

00000040 <reset>:
  40:   f000 f804   bl  4c <notmain>
  44:   e7ff        b.n 46 <hang>

00000046 <hang>:
  46:   e7fe        b.n 46 <hang>

00000048 <PUT32>:
  48:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
  4a:   4770        bx  lr

0000004c <notmain>:
  4c:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
  4e:   4903        ldr r1, [pc, #12]   ; (5c <notmain+0x10>)
  50:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (60 <notmain+0x14>)
  52:   f7ff fff9   bl  48 <PUT32>
  56:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  58:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
  5a:   bf00        nop
  5c:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  60:   20000400    andcs   r0, r0, r0, lsl #8
```

Looks good vector table in the right place, lsbit set on the vector table addresses, etc.

This is a very generic cortex-m program that should work on almost all cores some you may have to reduce the stack pointer init to 0x20000800 or smaller, likewise specify cortex-m0 on the command line instead of m4 to make it that much more generic, in this case it didnt generate any armv7-m  thumb2 extensions.

See what your tool says about this so.elf file generated, it does get simpler than this (remove the bl notmain) and only link flash.s into an elf, but not much simpler than this.  If it doesnt work then the problem may be something else, the tool may be looking for something.  If this is really a tiva c part then maybe the lm4flash tool will work and you dont need any guis, otherwise openocd should work if you have a SWD solution (an st nucleo or discovery board, or you are running on a ti launchpad, or a jlink or an ftdi breakoutboard with the right ftdi part (one that supports mpsse and the voltages are the right level for your target).  If it doesnt work then perhaps the tool is looking for something special in the elf file that is normally not required.  I assume before asking here you looked up that error message?

if it does load and appear to run and if you have a debugger, you can stop the cpu and read 0x20000400 and should see the 0x12345678 written by the program as further confirmation that the program did load and run.  Then examine my makefile, linker script and where it is used in the compile process, vs yours.

If you are trying to call all of the toolchain by using gcc then there are additional things you need to know, something like

```
arm-whatever-gcc other flags, -Xlinker '-T flash.ld' flash.s so.c -o so.elf
```

basically one or two -Xlinker or whatever the correct command line option is I think I use one -Xlinker for every ld option (-Xlinker -T -Xlinker flash.ld, but YMMV, I pretty much never have gcc do this extra work if I can avoid it prefer to call them directly, I let gcc call the assembler to make the compiled output an object, but other than that...).  Just running  gcc without options gives you the first level help then from that they show other things you can get help on and dig down (like passing parameters to the linker or assembler).